# Run a version that I have previously committed

Tags: xcode, commit

In my project I have been committing several times throughout history, I would like to know how I can run one of these versions. 
[Here are the versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeMbs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git checkout <commit sha>
```

Where *commit sha* of a previous commit in your example is **4c95c0**

If git complains about uncommited changes, commit them before checking out another commit with the above command.

If you don't want to keep uncommited changes you can run the following command:

```
git reset --hard <commit sha>
```

For more details, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit/4114122#4114122)